# NullpointerException when trying to find a WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to find a webelement using the following code:

```
private WebElement loc_Start;
public void clickButton() {
    loc_Start.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Start')]")).click();  
}
```

I don't see any mistake in the code. I also tried using @FindBy annotation, which gives me same error.

Comment: How is `loc_Start`'s value set?

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace? Depending on what's null, you may need to find out how/why that variable is null. Did you init your elements?

Comment: why are you using element.findElement shouldn;t it be driver.findElement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you are trying to implement it using PageFactory,

   `public class Page{
       @FindBy(xpath=" //button[contains(text(), 'Start')] ")
       private WebElement loc_Start; 
       public void clickButton() {
           // to initialize page - else u will get null pointer exception
           Page page = PageFactory.init(driver, Page.class);
           page.loc_Start.click(); 
       }
   }`
2. if not using page factory

   `private WebElement loc_Start = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Start')]"));
   public void clickButton() { 
       loc_Start.click (); 
   }`

   You are getting NullPointerException as you have not initialized loc_Start variable.

Comment: what about extending PageObject? or PageFactory?

Answer (score 0):

Your webelement is being used for some reason to find the element. Use your web driver.

Change loc_Start

```
 loc_Start.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Start')]")).click();
```

to your driver name

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Start')]")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

I too was getting the same error. the mistake I was doing was trying to find element using Webelement. Instead I should use Webdriver to do so, like

```
Webelement myelement=driver.findelement(by.xpath());
myelement.click() // or whatever function you want to perform.
```

After first initialisation of driver to webelement, we can use webelemnt directly to find element without using driver like

```
myelement.findelement(by.xpath()).click();
```

Note: this direct use of webelement for finding element after 1st initailsation of webdriver works function wise. In each function you have to use it like :-

```
Webelement myelement=driver.findelement(by.xpath());
myelement.click();
```

and then for next elements we can use ->

```
myelement.findelement(by.xpath()).click();
```

Hope this helps !!!